# OverflowError occurs when using cython with a large int

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

python 3.4, windows 10, cython 0.21.1

I'm compiling this function to c with cython

```
def weakchecksum(data):
   """
   Generates a weak checksum from an iterable set of bytes.
   """
   cdef long a, b, l
   a = b = 0
   l = len(data)
   for i in range(l):
       a += data[i]
       b += (l - i)*data[i]

   return (b << 16) | a, a, b
```

which produces this error:
"OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long"

I've also tried declaring them as unsigned longs. What type do I use to work with really large numbers? If it's too large for a c long are there any workarounds?

Comment: How about `cdef long long`?

Comment: same error, the number that is causing it is 2891688164113197

Comment: Consider making a big integer class?  It will be a linked list that contains digits

Comment: Yeah I considered that, I'm using cython to speed up some code and was hoping to avoid creating special classes that will increase overhead

Comment: signed long long on gcc, Ubuntu 14.04, is about 9.2e+18, from limits.h it is exactly `define LLONG_MAX    9223372036854775807LL` see http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Range-of-Type.html#Range-of-Type; unsigned long long is bigger.  Yes, saw you are on windows but this should really bit about how many bits fit into hardware-level algorithms.

Comment: got it, so the answer is there is no direct way to store a larger number

Comment: For a checksum, do you need to produce a result so long? Why not just use long or long long and mask down appropriately to ensure that it can't overflow? You could also use something like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift if you are moderately worried about collisions but don't care about cryptographic strength.

Comment: 2891688164113197 fits into int64_t which you should use. have you tried that with `from libc.stdint cimport int64_t`?

Comment: if you shift 2891688164113197 by 16 bits you will overflow that as well.

Comment: With this technique, the longer the data gets, the larger the number you'll need and you'll eventually overflow any storage unless you have a dynamic "big integer" class. I agree with @shaunc. Checksums are usually hashes of the data. Have you considered a [simple checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum#Parity_byte_or_parity_word) algorithm, or [md5 hash](https://docs.python.org/2/library/md5.html)? Would these be appropriate to your needs?

Comment: I have considered using a different checksum algorithm, this one is a function from the rsync algorithm and is built for speed. It creates a checksum for each block of a file. I'm assuming replacing with md5 would incur a significant performance cost and would proabably nullify the benefit of using cython. I'll check it out.

Comment: simple & fast != "variable bit length" which is your current algorithm. Simply masking off potential overflow would be one way to go. But if you want fast, why do a multiplication, anyway? @cod3monk3ys checksum suggestion has some useful options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you make sure that your calculations are in c (for instance, declare i to be long, and put the data element into a cdefed variable or cast it before calculation), you won't get this error. Your actual results, though, could vary depending on platform, depending (potentially) on the exact assembly code generated and the resulting treatment of overflows. There are better algorithms for this, as @cod3monk3y has noted (look at the "simple checksums" link).

Comment: So I added 'i' to the cdef statement and re-ran it. Still got the same error. Also tried cdef long long a, b, l, i

Comment: Try `cdef long d ...` (and in loop) `d = data[i]` or use then use `d` in the calculation (or use `<<long>>data[i]`). You can compile with a flag to look at the actual c code generated w/ python lines in comments -- you should see that the calculation is a straight c expression when there are no python variables involved. (note cast I cant spell right in markup for some reason :))

Comment: perfect.. I had given up on an answer for this one. That did it. You're a genius. For those of you reading this in the future. I declared cdef long a, b, l, i, d, and changed every reference to data[i] to d.

Answer (score 13):

*cython* compiles *pyx* files to C, thus it depends on underlying C compiler.

Size of integer types in C varies on different platforms and operations systems, and C standard don't dictate exact implementation.

However there is de facto implementation conventions.

Windows for both 32 and 64 bit uses 4 bytes (32 bits) for `int` and `long`, 8 bytes (64 bits) for `long long`. The difference between Win32 and Win64 is size of pointer (32 bits for Win32 and 64 bits for Win64). (See [Data Type Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)] from MSDN).

Linux uses another model: `int` is 32 bits for both linux-32 and linux-64, `long long` is always 64-bit. `long` and pointers are vary: 32 bits on linux-32 and 64 bits on linux-64.

Long story short: if you need maximum capacity for integer type which doesn't changed on different platforms use `long long` (or `unsigned long long`).

The data range for `long long` is `[–9223372036854775808, 9223372036854775807]`.

If you need numbers with arbitrary precision there is [GMP library](https://gmplib.org/) -- de facto standard for high-precision arithmetic. Python has wrapper for it called [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2).