# OverflowError: int too big to convert in Cython

Tags: hashmap, cython

I am trying to implement a HashMap in Cython. This is just an exercise for familiar myself with Cython, hope to do more stuff with it soon.

Here are my codes:

```
#cython language_level=3

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from cpython.ref cimport PyObject, Py_INCREF, Py_CLEAR, Py_DECREF, Py_TYPE, PyTypeObject, Py_XDECREF, Py_XDECREF, Py_XINCREF

cdef struct Entry:
    long long key
    PyObject* value

cdef class HashMap:
    cdef Entry** table
    cdef long long size
    cdef long long capacity

    def __cinit__(self, long long capacity=16):
        cdef Entry** entry
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.size = 0
        self.table = <Entry**>malloc(capacity * sizeof(Entry))
        entry = self.table
        for i in range(self.capacity):
            entry[i] = <Entry*>malloc(sizeof(Entry))

    def __dealloc__(self):
        cdef Entry** entry
        for i in range(self.capacity):
            entry = <Entry**>self.table
            if entry != NULL:
                free(entry)
        free(self.table)

    cdef long long hash(self, long long x):
        x = (x ^ (x >> 30)) * 0xbf58476d1ce4e5b9
        x = (x ^ (x >> 27)) * 0x94d049bb133111eb
        x = x ^ (x >> 31)
        return x

    cpdef put(self, long long key, object value):
        cdef Entry** entry
        key = self.hash(key)
        if len(self) == 0:
            self.table[0].key = key
            self.table[0].value = <PyObject*>value
            self.size += 1
            return        
        entry = <Entry**>self.table
        for i in range(self.capacity):
            if entry == NULL:
                entry[0].key = key
                entry[0].value = <PyObject*>value
                self.size += 1
                break

    cpdef get(self, long long key):
        cdef Entry** entry
        find_key = self.hash(key)
        entry = <Entry**>self.table
        for i in range(self.capacity):
            if entry[0].key == find_key:
                return <object>(entry[0].value)
        raise KeyError(key)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size
```

After I built and test the codes with the following:

```
>>> from hashmap.hashmap import HashMap
>>> hm = HashMap()     
>>> hm.put(27, "hello")
```

I encountered the following error:

```
OverflowError: int too big to convert
Exception ignored in: 'hashmap.HashMap.hash'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

Initially I used `int` and changed to `long long` due to [OverflowError occurs when using cython with a large int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877845/overflowerror-occurs-when-using-cython-with-a-large-int).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your constants in the `hash` function are not typed, so cython is treating them as python integers (arbitrarily big, not wrapping), then doing the math in this system which gives a number bigger than can be assigned back into `x`, giving the OverflowError. The fix is something like

```py
cdef long long hash(self, long long x):
   x = (x ^ (x >> 30)) * <long long>(0xbf58476d1ce4e5b9)
   x = (x ^ (x >> 27)) * <long long>(0x94d049bb133111eb)
   x = x ^ (x >> 31)
   return x
```

However note that you currently also have a memory management bug in your `put` function, which will cause a crash when trying to `get`...

Comment: Thank you for your response! Would you mind sharing what is the memory management bug?

Comment: Your will need to `Py_INCREF`' the `value` somewhere - at the moment if you call `hm.put(27, "hello")` then "hello" will be CG'ed at the end of the function, and you won't be able to `get` it later. (You will also want to `Py_DECREF` at some point)